# Search value in MS Access Database in C# not working

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am having a problem with my the connection between my MS Access Database and C#. What I am trying to do is that when I insert a specific set of words and numbers, the information of a person living in a department will appear. It is not the principal key, but when I change the value to the principal, it didn't work either.

Here is my code

```
    double pf, pi, pa, va, vb;
//pf = final point
//pi = principal point
//pa = actual point
//va = actual value
//vb = searched value
        private void TxtBuscar_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
            {
                if (Form1.FrmBase.TxtBusquedaDeptoBase.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("NO HAY INFORMACIÓN EN LA BASE DE DATOS / NO INFORMATION IN THE DATABASE");
                    TxtBuscar.Text = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    int i;
                    Form1.FrmBase.Registros.MoveLastItem.PerformClick();
                    pf = double.Parse(Form1.FrmBase.Num_Reg.Text);
                    Form1.FrmBase.Registros.MoveFirstItem.PerformClick();
                    pi = double.Parse(Form1.FrmBase.Num_Reg.Text);
                    vb = double.Parse(TxtBuscar.Text);
                    for (i = 0; i <= pf; i = i + 1)
                    {
                        va = double.Parse(Form1.FrmBase.TxtBusquedaDeptoBase.Text);
                        if (vb == va)
                        {
                            TxtNombre.Text = Form1.FrmBase.TxtNombreBase.Text;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Form1.FrmBase.Registros.MoveNextItem.PerformClick();
                        }
                        pa = double.Parse(Form1.FrmBase.Num_Reg.Text);
                        if (pa == pf)
                        {
                            if (vb != va)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("NO HAY INFORMACIÓN EN LA BASE DE DATOS / NO INFORMATION IN THE DATABASE");
                                TxtBuscar.Text = "";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I have another Form (FrmBase), which is directly connected to the database, that is why I do not have the OLEDBConnection values and all of that.

Thanks in advance,
Andrés Fuentes

Comment: coding advice, use meaningful/descriptive names to variables

Comment: You force click on the form controls, but dont wait until the event is completed and the actions of those events are finished. Also, your code should have some serious refactoring. If you do the refactoring you could avoid doing the PerformClick stuff, this is a XY problem.